# What data type for value 11.1234 in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am wondering what data type I should use for storing `11.1234` in mySql?

I am not sure if I should use `varchar` or `int`. There is also some `decimal` data types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FLOAT` or `DECIMAL` is probably best.

From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html):

> The FLOAT and DOUBLE data types are
>   used to represent approximate numeric
>   data values [...] The DECIMAL and
>   NUMERIC data types are used to store
>   exact numeric data values. In MySQL,
>   NUMERIC is implemented as DECIMAL.
>   These types are used to store values
>   for which it is important to preserve
>   exact precision, for example with
>   monetary data.